# When does $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{7x}{x^2+1}-\frac{7C}{3x+1}dx$ converge?

Tags: improper-integrals

I am required to find the values of $C$ for which the integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{7x}{x^2+1}-\frac{7C}{3x+1}dx$$ converges.

I know by experimentation that it converges when $C=3$. I am, however, unable to show this in a rigorous way.

I get stuck when I need to evaluate $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{7}{2}\ln(x^2+1)-\frac{7C}{3}ln(3x+1))$$

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Taking the hint from DonAntonio, I wrote the following solution. Let me know if there is anything wrong with the way I expanded DonAntonio's solution.

$$\frac{7x}{x^2+1}-\frac{7C}{3x+1}=7\cdot\,\frac{(3-C)x^2+x-C}{(x^2+1)(3x+1)}$$

When $C=3$
$$7\cdot\,\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(3-3)x^2+x-3}{(x^2+1)(3x+1)}=7\cdot\,\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x-3}{(x^2+1)(3x+1)}dx<\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^3}dx = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} dx$$
Which is convergent.

When $C\neq3$
$$7\cdot\,\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(3-C)x^2+x-C}{(x^2+1)(3x+1)}=7\cdot\,\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(3-C)x^2}{(x^2+1)(3x+1)}+7\cdot\,\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x-C}{(x^2+1)(3x+1)}dx$$

$$=|7\cdot\,\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(3-C)x^2}{(x^2+1)(3x+1)}dx+K| > \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^4} dx = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} $$
For some constant $K$

Which is divergent.

Comment: Find an equivalent of the integrand at $+\infty$ by reducing to same denominator...

Or find a necessary condition for your primitive to not have an infinite limit. Hint : $\ln(x^2+1)\sim 2\ln x$...

Comment: Collecting the logs together, the numerator behaves like $x^{7}$, so we want to know the values of $C$ for which $(3x+1)^{7C/3}$ behaves like $x^{7}.$ The binomial expansion behaves like its leading term, so the answer appears to be $C=3,$ but I can't even attempt anything more rigorous than this, at least right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

$$\frac{7x}{x^2+1}-\frac{7C}{3x+1}=7\cdot\,\frac{(3-C)x^2+x-C}{(x^2+1)(3x+1)}$$

Now, if $\;C\neq3\;$ then comparison with some multiple of $\;\frac1x\;$ will give you divergence...

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I expanded your solution in my question if that is okay with you.

Answer (score 1):

You know an antiderivative, namely
$$
\frac{7}{6}\bigl(3\ln(x^2+1)-2C\ln(3x+1)\bigr)=
\frac{7}{6}\ln\frac{(x^2+1)^3}{(3x+1)^{2C}}=
\frac{7}{6}\ln
  \frac{\bigl(1+\frac{1}{x^2\mathstrut}\bigr)^3x^6}
       {(3+\frac{1}{x})^{2C}x^{2C}}
$$
It's quite easy now to see when the limit is finite.

On the other hand, doing an asymptotic comparison with a power of $1/x$ is easier.